# Rotating monitor with a shortcut key

Tags: shortcut-keys, display-rotation

My Dell two in one laptop can be opened beyond 180 degrees to make an easel. However thi inverts the monitor. This is my prefered way of working with it at my desk at work where I have an external monitor mouse and keyboard.

When I boot into windows I can rotate the screens with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Key</kbd>. On Ubuntu it seems I have command line tools, and the System Panel shown below.

[image: Ubuntu Display Setting]

Since I often swap between a normal laptop and easel configuration, I'd prefer a keyboard shortcut to rotate the monitors if possible.

Comment: you say you have CLI tools... if you know the command to do it you can make a shortcut easily... have you investigated the CLI tools?

Comment: Please mention if you (don't) manage.

Comment: @Zanna that's a great idea if there is no built in one. I could probably send a patch too.